# Как создать столбец из значений другого DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть 2 DataFrame. Первый выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, данные дублируются, это кусок DataFrame, так нужно. Второй выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу в первый датасет добавить столбец значений, определяемый по второму датасету парой год-месяц?

Например, первое значение нового столбца должно быть 0.42 (т.к. 2011-12)

Пример:

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2011,1], [2011,2], [2011,2], [2012,3]], columns = ["year","month"]) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2011,0.5,0.4,0.3], [2012,0.9,0.8,0.7]], columns = ["Years","1","2","3"])
tmp = df2.set_index("Years").stack()
tmp.rename({'Years': 'year'}, inplace=True)
```

Merge не выходит, т.к. столбца месяц нет и переименовать не могу.

Comment: Это какой-то `pivot` уже надо использовать, подождём спецов )

Comment: первое понятно, а второе, где тоже 2011-12 ?

Comment: Никто не будет вбивать данные со скриншота толь для того, чтобы помочь вам. Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: 2011 год. 12 месяц (декабрь) - значение 0.42

Comment: @Антон, [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Алгоритм:

1. в `df2` - заменяете имена столбцов-месяцев на соответствующее число - `jan` -> `1`, `feb` -> `2`, etc.
2. создаете новый фрейм: `tmp = df2.set_index("Years").stack()`, переименовываете столбцы: `Years` -> `year`, столбец с номером месяца в `month`
3. делаете `merge`: `res = df1.merge(df2)`
4. всё!

---

Рабочий пример:

```
df2.columns = ["year"] + list(range(1, 4))
tmp = df2.set_index("year").rename_axis("month", axis=1).stack().reset_index(name="val")
res = df1.merge(tmp)
```

результат:

```
In [84]: res
Out[84]:
   year  month  val
0  2011      1  0.5
1  2011      2  0.4
2  2011      2  0.4
3  2012      3  0.7
```

PS если у вас что-то не получается, возникли ошибки или непонятны некоторые пункты данного ответа, [смотрите здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1306790/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%86-dataframe-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-dataframe#comment2307196_1306790)

Comment: Спасибо за совет, привел в вопросе простой пример кода. Стопорюсь на merge. После .stack() получаем объект series, в котором переименовать столбец с номером месяца не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Для приведенного вами в вопросе примера сработает такой вариант:

```
df1["val"] = df1.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[df2["Years"]==x["year"],
                                         x["month"].astype(str)].to_list()[0], axis=1)
```

df1, соответственно, будет:

```
  year  month  val
0  2011      1  0.5
1  2011      2  0.4
2  2011      2  0.4
3  2012      3  0.7
```

Однако, как видно на скриншоте, у вас изначально в колонке месяцы заведены именами. для простоты решения можно это все быстро переименовать, и решение несколько изменится:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[2011,1], [2011,2], [2011,2], [2012,3]], columns = ["year","month"]) 
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[2011,0.5,0.4,0.3], [2012,0.9,0.8,0.7]], columns = ["Years","jan","feb","mar"])
df2.columns = ["Years", *list(range(1, len(df2.columns)))]

df1["val"] = df1.apply(lambda x: df2.loc[df2["Years"]==x["year"],
                                         x["month"]].to_list()[0], axis=1)
```

Результат, понятное дело, будет такой же.

Comment: спасибо! все получилось!